# Изменение расширения файла для файлов в папке

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

кто-нибудь может подсказать по поводу изменения расширения файла с .xlsx на .xls?

Ситуация следующая.Есть множество таблиц в excel из которых мне нужно вытащить данные и сохранить в csv. Для этого я написал что-то типа парсера, который работает с помощью xlrd, т.е может работать только с xls файлом.

Но проблема в том что некоторые таблицы у меня сохраненные в новом формате .xlsx
Не хотелось бы вручную заходить в 100+ файлов и менять расширение на 97-2003 (.xls)

Поэтому я пошел дальше и написал прогу чтобы изменить все файлы в папке на нужное мне расширение:

```
import os
XlsxFilesInDir=[]
#os.rename("test.txt", "pytest.txt")
def FindFileByPrefix(pref,Listname):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
        for filename in files:
            #print(filename)
            if filename[-5:].find(pref)>-1:
                Listname.append(filename)
    print(pref,'IN CURRENT DIR:',Listname)
FindFileByPrefix('.xlsx',XlsxFilesInDir)

for XlsxFilesLine in XlsxFilesInDir:
    os.rename(XlsxFilesLine,XlsxFilesLine[:-5]+".xls")
```

Все отлично работает - меняет. Но проблема в том что, когда я пытаюсь xlrd работать с переименованными файлами у меня выдает ошибку:

> raise NotImplementedError("formatting_info=True not yet
>   implemented")
>
> NotImplementedError: formatting_info=True not yet implemented

Подозреваю что Пайтон считает что файл поврежден. Когда я пытаюсь открыть файл у меня пишет: "файл возможно поврежден и  бла бла". Но при нажатии Ок все нормально читается.

Как можно это обойти? Как поменять формат на .xls   "повреждая" файл

P.s я новичок в программировании, это не моя специализация, просьба не судите строго за мое подобие кода.

Comment: нашел еще вот такой вариант кода в интернете, но результат такой же(

Comment: import os, sys
for filename in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))):
    base_file, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if ext == ".xlsx":
        os.rename(filename, base_file + ".xls")

Comment: Наводящий вопрос, который объяснит в чем проблема. У вас есть файл `anime.avi` и вы его переименовываете в `anime.gif`. Файл после этого станет гифкой или структурой останется видео?

Comment: ЕМНИП, `xlrd` умеет читать и `.XLS` и `.XLSX` файлы - зачем их переименовывать? Эти файлы имеют разные форматы - расширение позволяет различить формат. Переименовав файлы вы сбили с толку `xlrd`

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать библиотеку `pandas` для работы с таблицами.

Устанавливается просто через `pip`

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel("./my_table.xlsx", sheet_name="Лист1")
data.to_csv("./my_table.csv", index=None)
```

в `read_excel` мы указываем имя файла и имя листа, если лист всего один `sheet_name` можно не указывать

в `to_csv` передаем имя файла для сохранения, `index=False` делаем для того чтобы в csv файле не было первого столбца с номерами строчек